# express.static : Cannot GET /

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, server

I'm learning how to use node.js on this blog/website: http://blog.modulus.io/absolute-beginners-guide-to-nodejs

Everything worked fine until I got to the part *Doing Something Useful - **Express***

Express seemed to install fine with npm.

Here's my code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Public'));

app.listen(8080);
```

I put that into a file called test.js and put it in a folder called `Public`.
In that folder I also added a html doc with just a few words.

On the browser ´http://localhost:8080´ shows up with **Cannot GET /** and ´http://localhost:8080/index.html´ shows **Cannot GET /index.html**

Comment: "Public" or "public" ?

Comment: If you put it in a directory called `Public` why are you telling Node to look in one called `public`?

Comment: sorry I meant Public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the public folder on the same level as your `test.js` file, like this

```
.
├── Public
│   └── index.html
└── test.js

1 directory, 2 files
```

It seems that you put your test.js in your Public directory.

`__dirname` means the name of the directory of the current file, that is why your `Public` directory should be in the same folder than your js file.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I had same problem. Public folder was not at the same level index.ts